# Node.js and Jest: Testing promise loop, count how many times function has been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to test my code using JEST, but I'm having some issues. I want to check, if `restart()` function has been called.

My code works like this, it's waiting for the data, and if there's no data it's calling the same function again. Basically something like a loop.

myCode.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    getSomething: async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("");
            }, 1000);
        });
    },
    doSomething: async () => {
        const data = await module.exports.getSomething();
        if (!data) {
            return module.exports.restart();
        }
        return data;
    },
    restart: async () => {
        return module.exports.doSomething();
    }
};
```

myCode.test.js file:

```
const myCode = require("./exampleCode")

describe("test", () => {
    test("Is it doing something more than once?", async () => {
        const restartSpy = jest.spyOn(myCode, 'restart');
        myCode.doSomething()
        expect(restartSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
})
```

My problem is that `expect(restartSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` is returning false.

The question is - what I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to test this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I've found a workaround.

```
describe("test", () => {
    test("Is it doing something more than once?", async () => {
        myCode.restart = jest.fn()
        const restartSpy = jest.spyOn(myCode, 'restart');
        await myCode.doSomething()
        expect(restartSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
})
```

I'm overwriting `restart()` function. So now, I'm able to add `await` to `doSomething()` function and it will no longer be inifinite loop. Now I can check if the restart function has been called

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is the lack of `await` before `myCode.doSomething()`. All your functions are asynchronous, so you need to wait for them to finish before checking the spy:

```
await myCode.doSomething();
```

Another issue is the fact that it's an infinite recursion loop - jest will timeout after 5000ms (by default) if you won't modify the code that is calling `restart`, for example:

```
doSomething: async (restartCounter = 0) => {
    const data = await module.exports.getSomething();
    if (!data && ++restartCounter < 2) {
        return module.exports.restart(restartCounter);
    }
    return data;
},
restart: async (restartCounter) => {
    return module.exports.doSomething(restartCounter);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with await. Unfortunately, I can't really change the code that I have. I think that I will just add another variable passed to the function just for testing. Thanks Tomasz